# IOS 10 - is it OK to use both webkit-playsinline and playsinline?

Tags: ios, iphone, webkit, html5-video

With iOS 10, [Safari on iphones play videos inline](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html). I read on [webkit.org](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) that with iOS 10 webkit has unprefixed the `webkit-playsinline` attribute so you use just `playsinline` in the `video` tag now. **But**, "unfortunately, this change did not make the cut-off for iOS 10 Developer Seed 2" so for some iphones (presumably) you need to use `webkit-playsinline`. But to cover all iOS 10 iphones, including those after the Developer Seed 2 cut-off, do I use both `playsinline` and `webkit-playsinline` in the `video` tag or just `webkit-playsinline`?

**Update** (14 Dec 17). A friend testing my pages with an iphone 5, system 10.3.2, reports that the native player pops up when using just `webkit-playsinline` (without `playsinline`). In my own tests of pages with both, the Quicktime player is (thankfully) supressed